# Playing WAV file in Chrome fails

Tags: google-chrome, audio, nginx, wav

I'm writing web application where users can listen audio (WAV) files using soundmanager2. Application is running on Amazon micro instance, but static files are served from my university server. Everything seemed to work fine, but I encountered problem with playing audio from Chrome browser but ONLY when files are served from university server. The same file served from Amazon server works fine in all browsers.
If you want to test I paste links bellow.

Amazon (APACHE) - works on all browsers:

`http://54.213.28.46/1402773433419_test.WAV`

University server (NGINX) - works well in Firefox, IE 11 and old Opera, doesn't work in Chrome and new Opera: 
http://bazamazak.uw.edu.pl/test.WAV

I don't have access to NGINX configuration files, but I can contact admins and suggest configuration change. Do You have any idea what could be the problem?
I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to hints from admins, I have managed to solve this problem. It occurred that file with lowercase extension works fine so changing `test.WAV` to `test.wav` fixed everything.

Comment: we have wav files that won't play in chrome , only Firefox  , with the `groove music` app that is built into firefox   ,    I figured that i was search for a solution  ( call center,  interactive recordings  legacy stuff  )   and I tried the lower case and that didn't work