# Which web browser let us reproduce wav audio files from GCP buckets?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webbrowser-control, wav, audio-player

We need to label audio files wav from a Google Cloud Platform bucket, and we planned to go to the website interface https://console.cloud.google.com/storage and just play the wav files. This works on Safari, but it doesnt work on:
Chrome,
Mozilla,
Opera,
Internet Explorer.

What web browser is available on windows that let us play those audio files? can we add a plug in to one of them to make it reproduce those files?

We tried changing the extension WAV to wav but it is still not working.
[Playing WAV file in Chrome fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224312/playing-wav-file-in-chrome-fails)

We found another possible reason:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000322043&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1
"You can confirm from the list of samples above that some of the 8 kHz samples will not load - specifically any of the coding schemes with a bitrate of 13 or lower will not play in Chrome."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First verify the encoding for the audio files you want to play in the browser.
It is often the case that the file format is confused with the encoding, as explained by Google Cloud team in [their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding).

To determine your encoding, you can use the [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org) media library:

> ffmpeg -i audio_file.WAV

This should display information of your file encoding and the bit rate.
As in the source you mention, if those don't match the minimum browser requirements, then you could export your wav files using the standard **pcm_s16le** (16 bit long endian pulse-code modulation):

> ffmpeg -loglevel panic -i audio_file.WAV -f wav -bitexact -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 8k -ac 1 output_audio_file.wav